# Reducing high dimensionality as well as feature selection on multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, clustering, multivariate-analysis, high-dimensional

Lately I've been reading a lot about time series clustering as I want to search for similar patterns in my own data set. Even though I feel like I understand the basic concepts of this task I still get confused when talking about high dimensional- as well as multivariate time series.

While multivariate time series are time series with more than one variable (e.g. EEG-data), high dimensionality of a time series describes the length of a given time series. When calculating the distance between time series both of the described characteristics can lead to the so called "Curse of Dimensionality", thus compromising the quality of the calculated clusters. I hope this is right so far? Please intervene if not.

Nonetheless, while there are methods to cope with high dimensionality (dwt, dft, ...) and a high number of variables ([CLeVer](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2140900)), I just can't get a hold on a method to do both. A dwt on a multivariate time series for example. Do you guys know any method that is able to do that?

Furthermore, I read that more than 10 dimensions are considered high dimensional and thus need a usage of dwt or dft. However, in [this](http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/time-series-clustering-classification) example the authors cluster time series with a length of 60 data points and still get reliable results.